# How to Retrieve XML using Linq Lambda?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

When Databind() calls, It generates error at new Customers.
Please solve it only by linq with lambda.

The Error :

*object reference not set to an instance of an object*

```
IEnumerable<Customers> Customers = XDocument.Load("Customers.xml")
    .Descendants("Customer")
        .Select(x => new Customers
        {
            Name = x.Element("Name").Value,
            City = x.Element("City").Value,
            Contact = x.Element("Contact").Value
        });

grid.DataSource = Customers;
grid.DataBind();

public class Customers
{
    public Customers() { }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
}
```

The XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <City>Ney York</City>
        <Contact>2233</Contact>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>Albert</Name>
        <City>Sydney</City>
        <Contact>4455</Contact>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>David</Name>
        <City>Colombo</City>
        <Contact>6677</Contact>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>George</Name>
        <City>London</City>
        <Contact>8899</Contact>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Comment: And what does your XML look like?

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <City>Ney York</City>
    <Contact>2233</Contact>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Name>Albert</Name>
    <City>Sydney</City>
    <Contact>4455</Contact>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Name>David</Name>
    <City>Colombo</City>
    <Contact>6677</Contact>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Name>George</Name>
    <City>London</City>
    <Contact>8899</Contact>
  </Customer>
</Customers>

Comment: @Wajahat You can edit your question to add extra information you have rather than posting comments

Comment: thank you but please solve this problem as well :)

Comment: I guess you are trying to access to a non-existent XML element, like `Address` for example.

Comment: @Paolo Moretti removed that mistake but still having same problem...

Comment: @Wajahat It works fine for me with your XML

Comment: well it worked fine for me what manish answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this..

```
IEnumerable<Customers> Customers = XDocument.Load("Customers.xml").Element("Customers")
  .Descendants("Customer")
    .Select(x => new Customers
    {
        Name = x.Element("Name").Value,
        City = x.Element("City").Value,
        Address = x.Element("Address").Value
    });
```

Hope this work.

Answer (score 0):

Modify with Customers with 's'

```
  List<Customers> data =   XDocument.Load("Customers.xml").Descendants("Customers")
                                    .Select(x => new Customers
                                        {
                                            Name = x.Element("Name").Value,
                                            City = x.Element("City").Value,
                                            Address = x.Element("Address").Value
                                        }).ToList();
```